# Continous- integration software for cmake project hosted on github

Tags: testing, github, continuous-integration, cmake

We are looking for a software to run our test cases automatically.

We want a software which will run on our server (or a commercial), which automatically gets the newest commit on github. Then compiles the commit of the project with CMake and run Ctest on our test cases. The results should then be visualized on a nice website.

I had a look at CDash, but as the documentation is so bad I did not even get it to get the latest commit from github.

So my questions are:

- Is there a good tutorial to CDash? Except the bad wiki page.
- What software is available for running tests on new commits to github, what are their advantages and drawbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your second question, [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) is a robost and extensible continuous integration tool that can be integrated tightly with GitHub using [a plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+Plugin) (or loosely using standard Git support). It also supports [CMake via a plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/cmakebuilder+Plugin). Whether it has disadvantages that will make it less useful for you depends on your organization and build process, but I've found it to be highly customizable to a wide variety of processes. I recommend taking a look at it.

There's also a third-party [Ctest plugin](https://github.com/rpavlik/jenkins-ctest-plugin) available for Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

CDash works in pair with CTest. If you are already using CMake then it should be fairly easy to submit your testing results to CDash. I'd recommend reading the CTest documentation:

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Testing_With_CTest

You can either install your own CDash server or use Kitware's hosted server at my.cdash.org. You can test your server with a sample project available at:

http://www.cdash.org/cdash/resources/software.html